# substitute the elements of a vector with values from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I need to substitute the elements of a vector which match the elements of a particular column in data frame in R. 
Reproducible example:

```
a<-c("A","B","C","D")
b<-data.frame(col1=c("B","C","E"),col2=c("T","Y","N"))
```

I need to get the following vector:

```
new<-c("A","T","Y","D")
```

What I tried is:

```
new <- a
new <- b$col2[match(a, b$col1)]
```

which does the substitution, but converts the unmatched elements into NAs.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` in base R:

```
a<-c("A","B","C","D")
b<-data.frame(col1=c("B","C","E"),col2=c("T","Y","N"), stringsAsFactors = F)

replace(a, which(a %in% b$col1), b$col2[b$col1 %in% a])

#[1] "A" "T" "Y" "D"
```

Comment: thanks, I thinks this a cleaner solution! sorry, I cant upvote with low reputation

Comment: Just keep in mind, if using this solution, that since there's no `match`, the order of `col1` must be the same as the order of `a`. Swap rows 1 and 2 in `b` with `b <- b[c(2, 1, 3),]` and the output of this would be A, Y, T, D, while the output using `match` would still be A T Y D

Answer (score 2):

You can make a data.table from `a` and then update only the rows for which there is a match when joining with `b`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(b)

data.table(a)[b, on = .(a = col1), a := i.col2][]
#    a
# 1: A
# 2: T
# 3: Y
# 4: D
```

In base R you could use your current approach but replace the `NA`s with elements of `a` using `ifelse`

```
temp <- as.character(b$col2[match(a, b$col1)])
ifelse(is.na(temp), a, temp)
# [1] "A" "T" "Y" "D"
```

Comment: @Grant don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you

Comment: @denis, of course, I just did not have enough reputation to accept it quickly :)